# To evaluate the integral $\int_{1}^{2}e^{x^2}\ln(x^2)dx$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

To evaluate the integral

$\int_{1}^{2}e^{x^2}\ln(x^2)dx$.

I came across this while doing question

$$\int_{1}^{4}\int_{\sqrt y}^{2} \frac{e^{x^2}}{y}dxdy.$$
I changed order of integration and now stuck on single variable integration which i posted in this question

Thanks

Comment: Since wolframalpha gives the integral in terms of the erfi function, I think there is no hope to find a simple closed form.

Comment: Have you tried changing the double integral to a line integral through Green's theorem?

Comment: @MiguelAtencia No. How to do that ?

Comment: @MiguelAtencia But my textbook states answer without use of erf funtion\

Comment: Does your textbook explain line integrals and the Green's theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_theorem

Comment: I know to convert line integral to double

Answer (score 1):

Green's theorem states:
$$\int_C f(x,y) ds = \iint_D \left(\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \right) dx dy$$
where $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$, $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y), f_2(x,y))$ and $C$ is a closed curve that is the border of the domain $D$.

First, you have to "guess" $f(x,y)$ so that the form in the double integral matches your problem. 
EDIT: I had not the proper $f$, so the integral was incorrect.

Now parametrize the curve $C$. You can define three segments:
$$\begin{aligned}\alpha_1(t)&=(t,1) &\quad t&\in(1,2) & \qquad \alpha'_1(t)&=(1,0)\\
\alpha_2(t)&=(2,t) &\quad t&\in(1,4) & \qquad \alpha'_2(t)&=(0,1)\\
\alpha_3(t)&=(t,t^2) &\quad t&\in(2,1) & \qquad \alpha'_3(t)&=(1,2t)
\end{aligned}$$

Finally compute the line integral.